# WildCard query in parse database

Tags: python-2.7, parse-platform, parse-server

I would like to know is there a way that I can perform a wildcard query in the parse database?

The solution in python would  be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance. :-)

Comment: It looks like parse.com is shut down. http://blog.parse.com/

Comment: Yeah!
But the parse servers are still available through a lot of vendors ryt and also parse server can be hosted locally... I'm working on the parse sever and the code is written in python and came across a case where I have to use wildcard query... @Charlie

Comment: What do you mean a whildcard query?

Comment: A wildcard character is used to substitute any other character(s) in a string. So queries involving wildcard characters are wildcard queries. Ex: L__e might give "life" and "live" and any relevant strings

Answer (score 1):

You have the $regex operator that let you match a column against a regular expression.

Make sure your database is correctly indexed as those queries are expensive.

See more info here: http://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#queries